# Tailwind preselect and active/focus on a div/button

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Sorry about the bad title. I have 3 boxes on my big site. So on the phone verison of my 3 boxes. They join into one and you can select from the tabs at the top which of the inputs you wish to see. They all have hover and focus effects to make them look nice and smart. However they are all switched to the unselected position when you load the page. So i get 3 white backgrounds in each button. I want the first button to be preselected to be active. So its a different background colour when you load the page. It will look nicer and so on if i do. I cant figure it out. Im using tailwind and its just for phone size screens

```
.control__button {
@apply capitalize border-2 rounded-md text-center px-4 py-2 text-eco-green 
bg-white border-eco-green hover:bg-eco-green-med hover:border-eco-green-dark 
hover:text-white focus:bg-eco-green focus:border-eco-green-dark focus:text-white     
focus:hover:text-slate-200 dark:bg-black dark:text-eco-green font-poppins
}

<section className='grid border-2 border-eco-green rounded-md'>
        <div className='grid grid-cols-3 p-1 gap-1 '>
          <button
            className='control__button focus-within'
            onClick={() => {
              setElementSelected(AboutSections[0]);
            }}
          >
            People
          </button>
          <button
            className='control__button'
            onClick={() => {
              setElementSelected(AboutSections[1]);
            }}
          >
            Earnings
          </button>
          <button
            className='control__button'
            onClick={() => {
              setElementSelected(AboutSections[2]);
            }}
          >
            Projects
          </button>
        </div>

        {/* Articles  */}
        <article>
          <AboutElement elementSelected={elementSelected} />
        </article>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a component for the button and then loop those buttons, as you're repeating yourself. But when you do, simply apply `.focus()` to the first button element in the loop via JS. This will then pick up utility classes applied via Tailwind such as `focus:bg-eco-green`. A vanilla JS example is shown. Select the section the buttons appear in, loop the buttons, focus the first.

```
const section = document.querySelector("section.border-eco-green");
section.querySelectorAll("button");
button[0].focus();
```

DRY is a good standard to stick to btw and will serve you well.

If you have to click that button too as well as make it focused, you can add `.click()` as well

```
const section = document.querySelector("section.border-eco-green");
section.querySelectorAll("button");
button[0].focus();
button[0].click();
```

The main takeaway here is that Tailwind won't set a default focus state of an item, you have to do it yourself. It will observe the focus state once set though.

Also bear in mind, that focus (as an HTML standard) only works on interactive elements such as `a`, `button`, `input`, `select` - it will work on a `div`, but only of it's got a

```
tabindex="1"
```

applied.